# How to made a /n in typescript when i use a var with characters to insert in a info of a array? and how show the info in a label with [(ngModel)]

Tags: angular, ionic3

this is a part of my code of typescript:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class CosasService{
```

this is the var where i am makeing the string with \n:

```
  descripcion = 'Mi texto con \n <br/> un salto de línea <br> jeijud \n\ nj';  

  items2 = [
    {id:1,info:'Aumento de masa muscular',description: this.descripcion},
    {id:2,info:'Perdida de peso',description:'hola2'},
    {id:3,info:'Aumento de fuerza',description:'hola3'},
    {id:4,info:'Tiempo de entrenamiento',description:'hola4'},
    {id:5,info:'Suplementos',description:'hola5'},
    {id:6,info:'Cansancion',description:'hola6'},
    {id:7,info:'Recuperacion',description:'hola7'},
  ];
}

html:
<ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>vista</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="info.info"></ion-input>
  <ion-input [(ngModel)]="info.description"></ion-input>

</ion-content>
```

image:

[image: this is the view]

Comment: Try this approach: use &#10; instead of /n

Comment: If you want to input multiline text, you should use a textarea, not an input. And <br> is HTML. You don't want that in your text (unless you actually want the user to enter HTML markup, and not simple text containing newlines).

Comment: You have another problem, not in this code, code is run very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the two way data binding you can simply use a div element with `innerHtml` instead of `ion-input` so that ionic compiles the content of your variable as Html:

```
   <ion-content padding>
     <ion-input [(ngModel)]="info.info"></ion-input>
     <div [innerHtml]="info.description"></div>
  </ion-content>
```

if you need multiple lines inupt `<ion-textarea>` instead

```
 <ion-textarea rows="2"  [(ngModel)]="info.description" ></ion-textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `ion-textarea` for multiline content along with `\n` instead of `<br>` html tag.

```
descripcion = 'Mi texto con \n \n un salto de línea \n jeijud \n\ nj";
```

In your html,

```
 <ion-textarea [(ngModel)]="info.description"></ion-textarea>
```

Sample stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-5f7psf?file=pages/home/home.ts)